# How to get customer details from Cratejoy using Ajax?

Tags: ajax, cratejoy

Is there someone around who has experience with interacting with the Cratejoy Merchant API?

I got my access key today, however, I can't get it working.

What I want to do is pretty simple:
- Display on a page how many renewals a customer had. That's it.

I understand that I can query this information with the Merchant API (http://docs.cratejoy.com/docs/introduction2). However, I can't get it working.

Does someone of you have any experience with the Cratejoy Merchant API?

I tried with with the following code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
  import requests

  $.ajax({
url: 'https://api.cratejoy.com/v1/customers/408899124/',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Basic XXXaccesscodeXXXX',
    },

    # make the request
response = requests.get(url, auth=auth)
json_data = response.json()['results']

num_subs = json_data['num_subscriptions']

print ' {}: {}'.format(num_subs)


});

</script>
```

It's probably totally wrong, so I would really appreciate your input.

Comment: What do you mean by it is not working? Are you getting any error from API? Is it not returning expected Satan?

Comment: I get the following error message: 

SyntaxError: Unexpected keyword 'import'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a JQuery snippet that gets information about an imaginary customer with an id of 123456789.

```
<script>
/**
 * Handler for ajax success.
 */
function onSuccess(obj) {
  console.log(obj);
  // here's where you'd do something with the data.
}


/**
 * Makes the actual ajax call.
 */
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://api.cratejoy.com/v1/customers',
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Basic XXXaccesscodeXXXX' 
  },
  method: 'GET',
  data: {
    id: '123456789'
  },
  success: onSuccess
});
<script>
```

Sounds like you already figured this out, but note that the string XXXaccesscodeXXXX will need to be replaced with a base64 encoded string that was generated from 'username:password'. You can generate this encoded string using the tool at Base64Encode.org.

For example, if the username Cratejoy gave you for the merchant API was "stackoverflowbox" and the password was "BBGbbadjKSAJ123", then go to Base64Encode.org and enter this...

stackoverflowbox:BBGbbadjKSAJ123

...and click ENCODE. Then copy/paste the resulting string and replace XXXaccesscodeXXXX in the javascript above.

Another major gotcha: if you're running this code from an HTML page within a browser, then it's going to fail if it's running outside the cratejoy domain. If you're just building an internal tool, you can use Chrome with [this extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?utm_source=gmail) to allow such requests.

Once you get the pattern above working, then you can follow the [Merchant API docs](http://docs.cratejoy.com/docs/) to start requesting more information, like renewals. I haven't pulled renewal information myself yet, so I'm not sure how to do it. But hopefully this gets you going.